# How do I chose neo4j settings based on the properties of my graph.db?

Tags: neo4j

Currently I have a graph.db that looks like this:
I have 6 indexes, ~3x10^5 nodes, and ~6x10^5 relationships.

```
102B Mar 14 16:05 index
583B Mar 14 16:05 index.db
13K Mar 14 16:05 messages.log
78B Mar 14 16:05 neostore
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.id
72B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.labeltokenstore.db
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.id
444B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names.id
3.8M Mar 14 16:05 neostore.nodestore.db
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.nodestore.db.id
93B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.nodestore.db.labels
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id
26M Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db
153B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.id
178B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.index
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.index.id
710B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id
8.0K Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.strings
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id
20M Mar 14 16:05 neostore.relationshipstore.db
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.relationshipstore.db.id
58B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id
292B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id
82B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.schemastore.db
9B Mar 14 16:05 neostore.schemastore.db.id
102B Mar 14 16:05 schema
0B Mar 14 16:05 store_lock
```

My goal is to put 4x10^6 nodes and ~8x10^6 relationships into the database.

Queries of type `MATCH (n:nodelabel) RETURN n LIMIT 25` seem slow, and since this is not a complicated query, I'm thinking my queries are not the issue. How should I decide what memory settings to use? Or is there another issue? I'm not really sure what question to ask.

I'm running Neo4j on a dedicated Ubuntu server.

This is what I'm using:

```
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=50M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=50M
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=205M
```

Answer (score 0):

- What does your server look like?
- How much heap did you give Neo4j-server?
- From where do you measure your queries?
- Is it only the first run that's slow (disk), or subsequent runs too?
- Did you check your [disk config](http://structr.org/blog/neo4j-performance-on-ext4)?
- Can you share your graph.db/messages.log?